# Wordpress conditional menu plugin does not work

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a wordpress website and I am using the conditional menu plugin 
but that does not work.
I have the home.php template I added using the code

```
<?php if(!is_front_page() && is(home)) ?>
```

and I have used the

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

function in the index.php.
Moreover I have the following specific page templates:
 about-us,photos,vidos,contact
I have added those with the following  code:

```
<?php
    if(is_page(about-us)){
        get_template_part('template-parts/about');
    }
?>
```

The problem is the menu is not showing in the specific pages.
Can someone help me to fix it?

P.S:I used other plugins as well (like the Elementor plugin).

Comment: If you have an issue with a plugin, you should ask the plugin author on their own support forum. Having said that, you do have some basic WP/PHP errors - `is(home)` should be `is_home()` and `is_page(about-us)` should be `is_page("about-us")`

Comment: That was just a typo when I asked the question.Anyway I appreciate your comment.

Comment: Are you using The Loop in your template parts files of those specific pages?

Comment: No ,I am not using the loop in the custom pages.Should I use it?

Comment: Yes, I think you should use The Loop there.